# Can you charge for apps created on Google's App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a web app I'd like to create and I was thinking about building it on Google's App Engine, but I was curious if I would be able to charge for an app I create on there or if they only allow free ones?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. There is nothing in the Terms of Service that says you can't charge users of your App Engine app.

Answer (score 0):

You can make apps on GAE freely,but there are some services on GAE not free..